# UISearch bar : Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have some data in table view which I get from web service. I have a custom class (SaveContactView) which calls the table cell depending on count mutable array count. Even though I get the error in the following code,

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Mutable array == %@", mutableArray); // get only addresses of SaveContactView here.
        isFiltered = YES;
        filterdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSString *name in mutableArray)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; // error 
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filterdArray addObject:name];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.tableViewContact reloadData];
}
```

I think the problem is somewhere in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"SaveContactCell";
    ContactTableCell *cell = (ContactTableCell *)[self.tableViewContact dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *nib
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
             nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        else
        { 
             nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactTableCell_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
        }
            for (id object in nib)
            {
                if([object isKindOfClass:[ContactTableCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (ContactTableCell *)object;
                    break;
                }
            }

            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



        /*
        if(isFiltered == YES)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [filterdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }*/

        SaveContactView *saveContact;
        if(isFiltered == YES)
        {
            saveContact = [filterdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            saveContact = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        cell.name.text = saveContact.name;
        cell.companyLabel.text = saveContact.company;


    }
    return cell;
}
```

isFiltered is the BOOL value. mutableArray has all data. filteredArray has searched data.
Log for mutableArray is

```
Mutable array === (
    "<SaveContactView: 0x15d79a50>",
    "<SaveContactView: 0x15d2c920>",
    "<SaveContactView: 0x15d4a9e0>",
    "<SaveContactView: 0x15d50360>",
    "<SaveContactView: 0x15d1cf00>",
    "<SaveContactView: 0x15d20c30>"
)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the unrecognized selector that you're sending, according to the console logs?

Comment: log your `mutableArray`

Comment: i uploaded the log image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering on wrong objects. In your array you are putting SaveContactView objects, but you want to filter on their name.

```
for (SaveContactView *contact in mutableArray)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [contact.name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; // error 
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filterdArray addObject:contact]; // add contact, not string
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the following line
       for (NSString *name in mutableArray)

The elements in mutableArray seems to be of SaveContactView type. You should do something like below:

```
for (SaveContactView *saveContactView in mutableArray){
     NSString *name = saveContactView.name
........
```